# Poco HTTPServer aborted if logging from a thread started with Poco/Timer

Tags: c++, logging, debian, poco-libraries

If I set up and schedule a `Poco::Timer`

```
Poco::Timer timer{ 0, 10000 /* ms */ };

MyTask task;
timer.start(Poco::TimerCallback<MyTask>(task, &MyTask::onTimer));
```

where `MyTask` is

```
class MyTask
{
public:
    Task() : logger { Poco::Logger::get("TaskLogger") } {}

    void onTimer(Poco::Timer &timer)
    {
        this->logger.information("Logged");
    }
private:
    Poco::Logger &logger;
}
```

my HTTPServer built on top of [poco-libraries](/questions/tagged/poco-libraries) crashes with the message

```
Aborted
```

If I remove the line `this->logger.information(...);` from `MyTask::onTimer` the server executes normally. In fact, should I replace that line with

```
std::cout << "Logged" << '\n';
```

I can see the message being logged every 10 seconds.

---

Apparently I am not allowed to use `Poco::Logger` from other threads.

**MCVE** without a HTTPServer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Poco/Logger.h"
#include "Poco/Timer.h"

class MyTask
{
public:
    Task() : logger { Poco::Logger::get("TaskLogger") } {}

    void onTimer(Poco::Timer &timer)
    {
        this->logger.information("Logged");
    }
private:
    Poco::Logger &logger;
}

int main()
{
    Poco::Timer timer {0, 5000};
    MyTask task;
    poco.start(Poco::TimerCallback<MyTask>(task, &MyTask::onTimer));

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The `Logger` will never log.

---

**Q:** How can I log messages (using `Poco/Logger`) inside other threads?

---

System info

```
POCO version
poco-1.9.0

Compiler and version
gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516
g++ (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516

Operating system and version
Debian GNU/Linux 9.6 (stretch)
```

Comment: If you don't get any output on console, try to create *SimpeFileChannel*, attach it to your logger, and see if you are getting logs in file. BTW what version of g++ are you using?

Comment: @rafix07 added system info. I'll try the `SimpleFileChannel` and answer back